# What is the equivalent of "php artisan serve" for a CodeIgniter project?

Tags: php, codeigniter, composer-php, command-line-interface

I need to run CodeIgniter project from any location without the need to replace it on the directory (www) of my WAMP server. So I want to use the CLI and Composer for this.

For Composer autoloading I follow these instructions from this [link](https://forum.codeigniter.com/thread-64487.html).

Here is my config file:

```
$config['composer_autoload'] = TRUE;
```

And my `composer.json`:

```
"config": {
"vendor-dir": "application/vendor"
},
```

After that I run `composer update` to create the `vendor/` folder.

However when I tried to run the project using CLI like so:

```
php index.php MYController_1 Methode_1
```

Instead of opening and running the web application through web browser, the source code of this page is printed to the console.

What is the equivalent of Laravel's `php artisan serve` for CodeIgniter?

Comment: How to run the app using cli without needing to relocate it at www directory

Answer (score 17, accepted):

### Laravel

`php artisan serve` is [how Laravel starts a local development server](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/installation#your-first-laravel-project):

> After the project has been created, start Laravel's local development
> server using the Laravel's Artisan CLI `serve` command:
>
> ```
> cd example-app
>
> php artisan serve
> ```

### CodeIgniter v3

CodeIgniter version 3 doesn't have an equivalent command to this, but you can use PHP's built-in webserver [as Lázaro suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50049605/354577):

```
php -S localhost:8000 index.php
```

### CodeIgniter v4

If you are using CodeIgniter version 4 you can start its local development server [with `php spark serve`](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/installation/running.html#local-development-server):

> #### Local Development Server
>
> CodeIgniter 4 comes with a local development server, leveraging PHP’s
> built-in web server with CodeIgniter routing. You can use the `serve`
> script to launch it, with the following command line in the main
> directory:
>
> ```
> php spark serve
> ```
>
> This will launch the server and you can now view your application in
> your browser at http://localhost:8080.
>
> ##### Note
>
> The built-in development server should only be used on local
> development machines. It should NEVER be used on a production server.

Comment: Thank you Chris for this comprehensive answer, but when I run php serve in codeigniter directory I have this error  "Could not open input file: serve"

Comment: @Hana90, it looks like this answer only applies to CodeIgniter version 4. I guess you're on version 3? In that case Lázaro's answer is probably best.

Comment: I download v4 and the same error I got when running this command in the project directory

Comment: @Hana90, ah, I've got it! The command is actually `php spark serve` for v4. I guess the documentation is wrong (the product is still in active development, after all). I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 4):

PHP has a [build in server](http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.webserver.php) that you can use. Just run

```
php -S localhost:8000 -t YOUR_PROJECT_FOLDER/
```

Codeigniter itself has nothing like a 'php artisan serve'

Comment: Listening on http://localhost:8000
Document root is C:\wamp\www\projectNAme'
Press Ctrl-C to quit.

Comment: but there is no app opening on the browser.

Comment: I think you should actually point at `index.php`, not `public/`.

Comment: The argument after the `-t` is the root directory you want the server to start with. It is supposed to be the same as the were is your `index.php` is located

Answer (score 0):

`php spark serve` for CodeIgniter4.*.

Comment: This has already been explained in the accepted answer.